# How to fetch email Id of user using django social auth for facebook and google

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

I can successfully login using facebook and google but all I can display is the username. Now I want to show the username as well. How do I go about doing it. I read that facebook doesnt provide details like email ID by default and details like these need to be requested. I have added that but I dont know how that data is to be accessed.
settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '***'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '***'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
  'locale': 'ru_RU',
  'fields': 'id, name, email, age_range'
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '***'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '***'
GOOGLE_DISPLAY_NAME = ''


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'thirdauth',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
   'django.core.context_processors.debug',
   'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
   'django.core.context_processors.media',
   'django.core.context_processors.static',
   'django.core.context_processors.tz',
   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
   'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
   'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
   'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

views.py

```
context = RequestContext(request,
                           {'request': request,
                            'user': request.user})
   return render_to_response('home.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

User the Following code to get the user email
Also make sure that you are getting not only profile but also email in the  scope.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


     id=request.user.id
     user = User.objects.get(id=id)
     user_email = user.email
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some great packages in django to handle social auth. I prefer you should use [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Allauth already have this use case solved. When a user is asked to login with facebook, allauth fetches email after asking for consent through a consent screen. And you can check these emails and user account by using django admin panel once [allauth setup](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) and migrations are done.